# 'No Entity Framework provider found' for EF 6 and SQLite 1.0.105.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, sqlite

I have tried some answers on similar questions for previous versions, but none seem to work:

- Adding a third provider (Sqlite) to the App.config.
- Changing the connection string provider from Sqlite.EF56 to Sqlite.

**What works**: updating from database (after a change in Sqlite Studio).

**What doesn't work**: generating a database from an updated model.

**Error message**: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.Sqlite.EF6'.

I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have installed *sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.105.2.exe* (for the visual designer) and then added NuGet packages like so:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />   
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.105.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Core" version="1.0.105.2" targetFramework="net45" />    
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" version="1.0.105.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Data.SQLite.Linq" version="1.0.105.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

My App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="data03Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Data03.csdl|res://*/Data.Data03.ssdl|res://*/Data.Data03.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\Users\Frederik\Documents\Data\data03.db&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try to compile your project as x86 instead of AnyCPU

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider ?

Comment: @Isma that's already the case

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `DbProviderFactories` and `entityFramework` sections are present in your main project's (start-up project) config file. You probably have data access in separate project.

Answer (score 0):

in your config file:

```
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

you need to add in providers node

```
<provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
```

as many devs reported that it is needed as well. I have also experienced that.

also make sure your connection string is referencing the provider "System.Data.SQLite" not "System.Data.SQLite.EF6"